# AngularJS $http.post demorando muito

Tags: angularjs, web-service, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma web API feita em php que acessa um banco MySql que tem retorno em JSON e estou usando Ionic + AngularJS para desenvolver um App que vai usar essa API.

No meu arquivo services.js eu criei uma factory pra cada entidade do meu sistema, desse maneira :

```
var apiUrl = "http://minhaUrl/";

angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Login', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){
  return {
    verifica: function(emailParam, senhaParam){
      return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: apiUrl + "api/login/verificaLogin/",
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
          email: emailParam,
          senha: senhaParam
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      });
    } 
  }
})
.factory('Eventos', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){
  return {
    getCurrent: function(){
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl + "api/eventos/listareventos/",
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(
        {
          param1: val1,
          param2: val2
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      });      
    }
  }
});
```

No arquivo controller.js eu implemento o login dessa forma

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, Login, Eventos){

  //logar() é disparado no ng-click de um botão no HTML
  $scope.logar = function(){
    if($scope.Login.email && $scope.Login.senha){
      Login.verifica($scope.Login.email, $scope.Login.senha)
        .then(function(resp){
          if(resp.data.sucesso){      //(1) Aqui ele demora menos de 1 segundo para entrar    

            localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(resp.data.login));

            Eventos.getCurrent().then(function(respEventos){
               $scope.Evento = respEventos.data.eventos[0]; //(2) Aqui demora uns 30 segundos pra entrar
            });

          }
          else{
            $scope.showAlert('E-mail ou senha incorretos!', 'Confirme as informações antes de logar.');
          }
        }, function(){
          $scope.showAlert('Não foi possível completar a ação', 'Tente novamente mais tarde');
        });
    }
    else{
      $scope.showAlert('E-mail ou senha incorretos!', 'Confirme as informações antes de logar.');
    }
  }
});
```

Primeiramente o usuário loga no aplicativo com seu e-mail e senha, depois de verificar a identidade dele o app deve carregar o evento atual.(1) A primeira requisição, do login, é executada rapidamente, porém a (2) segunda demora muito para entrar no método then().
Já tentei usar success no lugar, porém fica da mesma maneira.
Eu testei o serviço com exatamente os mesmos parâmetros no aplicativo do chrome [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) e o tempo de resposta foi por volta de 600ms.

[image: Tempo de resposta do WebService]

Será que o problema é com meu servidor? Se o problema é com o servidor, porque é executado bem mais rápido no ARC? Pode ser algum problema relacionado com uma requisição estar dentro da outra?

Testei o aplicativo pelo Google Chrome, pelo Ionic View no celular e pelo app nativo para android, todas as versões encontram o mesmo problema, porém no Chrome aparenta executar mais rápido.

Comment: Já fiz algo parecido e não demorou não. Inclusive deixei o código até melhor quando usei `chain` nos requests. por exemplo: `login.verifica().then(function() { if (tal) return; else return Eventos.getCurrent();  }).then(function() { // Verifico aqui a promessa do Eventos });`, mas 30 segundos é uma coisa estranha. Caso já tenha resolvido, poste pra nós o que era.

Comment: @lordcheat Para resolver o problema eu refiz o método PHP da API trazendo todas as informações que eu precisava em uma requisição só. Como a primeira requisição era executada rapidamente deu certo, mas não descobri o porquê da demora, infelizmente.